# Why doesn't this getOrDefault method return 1?

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Mike", 1);
System.out.println(map.get("Mike")); // 1
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(map.get("Mike"), 0)); // 0
```

The second result is 0. I want to know why 0 is output. Because I expected output 1.

Comment: Because 1 isn't a key in your map?

Comment: The correct version is `map.getOrDefault("Mike", 0)`.  Not `map.getOrDefault(map.get("Mike"), 0)`.

Comment: Can you indicate specifically *why* you expect `map.getOrDefault(1, 0)` to return `1` for your `map`?

Comment: `map.getOrDefault(map.get("Mike"), 0)` translates to `map.getOrDefault(1, 0)`, and since your map doesn't have `1` as a key, it returns the default value `0`

Comment: Changed "does" to "doesn't" in the title to reflect the actual issue. Also, closing this due to it being a typo.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `map.getOrDefault(map.get("Mike"), 0)`, `ap.get("Mike")` returns `1`, it means that **you are trying to get the value associated with key 1 in the map**, there is no key, and it results in the default value, which is 0.

So, you can solve this by using `"Mike"` as a key directly:

```java
map.getOrDefault("Mike", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map#getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) return the mapping for the given key (first argument). If no such mapping is found it returns the default value given in the second argument. You can think of it as

```
if (map.contains(key)) {
    return map.get(key);
} else {
    return defaultVal;
}
```

In your case `map.get("Mike")` returns `1`. So, the next line effectively becomes `map.getOrDefault(1, 0)`. But your map doesn't have any entry for `1`. So, it returns the default value 0.